# GNAT Studio (GPS) not launching on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, ada, gnat-gps

I've just installed the Adacore's IDE GNAT Studio on Windows 10. The installation process went smoothly, then I added the binary directory to the path (C:\GNAT\2020\bin in my case). I can compile a simple program using the CLI (gprbuild) but the IDE itself isn't working. I found a similar question on superuser [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1456778/gnat-programming-studio-not-launching) but there's no answer.

Here are the links to the package I installed :

[Window executable x64](https://community.download.adacore.com/v1/966801764ae160828c97d2c33000e9feb08d4cce?filename=gnat-2020-20200429-x86_64-windows-bin.exe)

[Readme file](https://community.download.adacore.com/v1/95ddc9742e5a57fef81e9a4196e2661613eb2842?filename=README.txt)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Perhaps describing precisely the "isn't working" could be helpful. What happens exactly when you start C:\GNAT\2020\bin\gnatstudio.exe ? On my Windows 10 PC GNAT Studio is working perfectly.

Comment: If you try to start it by hand from a command prompt (console), do you get any more diagnostic messages? Also, is it earlier in the path than your Python installation?  It uses Python and may require a specific version.

Comment: just tried it on my old Win 7 dust collector (I don't use windows much), and it works just fine. You could check for any logs in your user folder (under .gnatstudio\logs)

Comment: the IDE also isn't very good, actually. I use gprbuild directly from vim, and have code completion and reference finding through [ada_language_server](https://github.com/AdaCore/ada_language_server/), which uses libadalang to analyse the code. You can go the ada_language_server route for many editors, such as atom, kakuine, sumlime text or VScode. See [langserver.org](https://langserver.org/) for details on this approach. I really hope it heralds the end of the IDE-per-programming language era.

Comment: I tried to launch it from the CLI, but there's no error message and nothing actually happens i.e the gnat studio interface doesn't get displayed. The same thing happens when I launch gnat studio from the bin directory itself C:\GNAT\2020\bin\gnatstudio.exe by double clicking on it.

Answer (score 2):

I finally managed to launch GNAT Studio on my computer. After googling a bit, I found [this page](http://soc.if.usp.br/manual/gnat-gps-doc/html/Solving-Problems.html) listing common GNAT problems. There, I learned that GNAT Studio not launching may be related to the [.gps](http://soc.if.usp.br/manual/gnat-gps-doc/html/Files.html#Files) folder. As my GPS install was fresh, I didn't need to create a new folder. However, I suspected that the .gps folder may be inaccessible due to my user folder name containing spaces and special characters. I then proceeded to change my username first and user folder name second. After that, I reinstalled GNAT Studio and it worked fine.

Here are the references I used :

[How to change your account name on Windows 10](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/change-account-name-windows-10/)

[Another article about changing your account name on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-account-name-windows-10-sign-screen)

[How to rename the user folder in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/a/1346983/1185033)

[Microsoft recommendation for renaming the user folder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2454362/renaming-a-user-account-does-not-automatically-change-the-profile-path)

Answer (score 0):

Adding GNATSTUDIO_HOME to my env variables fixed this problem for me.